# ScrollViewer content is scrolling over other parts of window

Tags: wpf, scroll

I have the following as part of my XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBar Name="toolbar1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="41" Background="#FFA5D95A">
        //other controls
    </ToolBar>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Items}" 
                 ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource entryItemTemplateSelector}">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

I want the scrool bar to move the items in the ListBox just to the top of the WrapPanel, and then to stop showing them when they get to the top; in stead, these items scroll into the ToolBar at the top.

[image: Image of the content scrolled too far]

What am I doing wrong?

Note: Haing been asked, here are the DataTemplates I currently have; `EntryItemHost` is a type derived from `WindowsFormsHost`.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="folderTemplate">
        <my:EntryItemHost Item="{Binding}" 
                          Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Background}" 
                          DoubleClick="FolderDoubleClick" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
        <my:EntryItemHost Item="{Binding}" 
                          Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Background}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: could you also share entryItemTemplateSelector with the item template which is used? also post a screen of the issue, I can't simulate here.

Comment: Are you using native WinForm controls inside the ScrollViewer?

Comment: You displayed code does *not* reproduce your problem. Please provide a valid example that does.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting ListBox `Template` set the `ItemsPanel` and remove the `ScrollViewer`

sample

```xml
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBar Name="toolbar1"
             DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             Height="41"
             Background="#FFA5D95A">
        //other controls
    </ToolBar>
    <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Items}" 
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource entryItemTemplateSelector}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

notice that I have replaced the template with ItemsPanel and restricted the width to the listbox

I made this based on the assumptions, let me know is this not what you are looking for

Comment: I'm getting the same results now that I did before.

Comment: I think I need to see the data template as well, could you share the same too?